# C++ standard sort documentation issue

Tags: c++

My copy of the C++ standard document documents the standard sort function.

25.4.1.1 sort

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
...
Effects: Sorts the elements in the range [first,last).
```

> Requires: RandomAccessIterator shall satisfy the requirements of
>   ValueSwappable (17.6.3.2). The type of *first shall satisfy the
>   requirements of MoveConstructible (Table 20) and of MoveAssignable

OK - but shouldn't it also require that the elements referred to also be comparable?

I would expect the "Requires" clause to include something like:

"type which results from dereferencing the `RandomAccessIterator` should satisfy the requirements of `LessThanComparable`."

Or better yet

"`iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type` should satisfy the requirements of LessThanComparable."

since 24.4.1 says in part "it is required that if `Iterator` is the type of an iterator, the types ... `iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` be defined"

Why isn't such language included. Surely the sort function can't sort elements which can't be compared.

Comment: Isn't that covered by [alg.sorting]/1-4?

Comment: @TonyTheLion "The above rules imply that RandomAccessIterator also implements `LessThanComparable`." Looks like it.

Comment: @TonyTheLion @JAB comparing the *iterators* is different from comparing objects of the type of `*i`, where `i` is an iterator.

Comment: @DyP True. I was thinking about cases where the sorting could be done using the iterator type's overloaded functions rather than those of the dereferenced values, but I guess that would only be for sorting groups of iterators.

Answer (score 4):

- OK - but shouldn't it also require that the elements referred to also be comparable?

If you scrolled up above in the standard you would have found these requirements (under § 25.4) for the sorting algorithms:

> All the operations in 25.4 have two versions: one that takes a
>   function object of type Compare and one that uses an operator<.

Which means it's already enforced in the standard for the types to be required to use `operator<` *or* a custom comparator.

The custom comparator has the following requirements:

> `Compare` is a function object type (20.8). The return value of the
>   function call operation applied to an object of type `Compare`, when
>   contextually converted to `bool` (4), yields true if the ﬁrst argument
>   of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise. `Compare` comp
>   is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation. It is
>   assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the
>   dereferenced iterator.